How does the Judo Kyu graduation system work in Chile?
How does the Judo Kyu graduation system of the FEDERACIÓN DE JUDO DE CHILE work for kids and adults? And which ranks are there?

Just to be clear, you are looking for belt ranks, correct?

@MacacoBranco Yes. And also the requirements the players have to meet.

The federation lists the following requirements for each kyu and dan grade:









https://www.fejuchile.cl/descargas/#documentos (regalamento-de-ascenso-2016-2020.pdf)


Oh wow the kyu program looks a bit like it hadn't changed much since some Japanese introduced Judo to Chile about 100 years ago
